window.open() in Chrome returns null even though the window opens
In Chrome version Version 127.0.6533.101 I'm doing
const { document: a } = window.open("", "GeometryDocumentation", "width=480,height=640");

I get the error:

Cannot destructure property 'document' of 'window.open(...)' as it is null

Despite this, the window is opening with the correct height and width. I'm not blocking popups in Chrome nor do I have an ad-blocker. I don't get this error in Safari.
I'm making this call from inside an iframe so maybe there's a CORS issue? Although the iframe domain matches its parent.

Is this triggered by a user interaction in the iframe?

@DavidBradshaw Yep. When they click a button.
